# What charge controller would be required to charge a 12v battery with 40w solar panel?

Tags: solar-cell

I am looking to setup a 40w (or similar) solar panel on my SUV to charge a 12v deep cycle (AGM) battery for use when we're camping and that sort of situation. I am unsure as to what sort of charge controller and what amperage charge controller I am going to need for such a setup.

Could anyone please suggest what sort of charge controller would be recommended for this situation and why?

Answer (score 1):

Well really any solar lead acid charger rated to 4A or more (40W/12V = 3.3A). But try and get a *solar* charge controller, they are better designed to deal with the variable nature of solar panels than regular battery chargers

Answer (score 1):

A 40 W solar panel will in the worst case put out 3.3333 amps.   Volts x amps = watts, 12 x 3.3333 = 40.

I would aim for a somewhat larger charge controller simply so you  aren't running the controller at limits and have some headroom if you get a good price on a second panel.  We don't do "shop for you" here but quality is very important, too much foreign junk, Morningstar is a top brand and their bottom-end controllers seem to retain their build quality.

You're getting just big enough that it's almost worth talking [MPPT](http://www.blueskyenergyinc.com/uploads/pdf/BSE_What_is_MPPT.pdf).  Plain "PWM" charge controllers are simple DC-DC converters which output correct battery charge voltage.  They draw from the solar panel at "whatever" voltage and current.  An MPPT controller "scans the panel", trying several different current draws to see what voltage the panel will give at that current. It multiplies Volts x Amps = Watts, and then, **optimizes for Watts**.  It jigs the current draw up and down periodically, always hunting for best Watts.  It does a simple DC-DC conversion to battery charge voltage. This gives you [absolute max watts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpL4RR0_QyM) out of your panel, although it costs somewhat more.

Another charge controller feature is "dump".  It's not required for solar, but it's a nice feature when the panel is rockin' but the battery is full.  Dump could be used to run the blower fan to keep the car cooler inside.